# Convert SQL Server table data from XML to JSON

Tags: sql-server, json, xml, sql-server-2012

I have a complex sql with multiple joins involved in it like the below.

```
select * from 
Table1 inner join Table2 on t1.id=t2.id
...
...
...
for xml path
```

I just converted the result set to xml then I am trying to convert the xml to Json format using the following function code.

```
Create FUNCTION [uf_xmltojson] (@XMLResult XML)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
Begin
Declare  @JSONVersion NVarchar(max), @Rowcount int
Select @JSONVersion = '', @rowcount=count(*) from @XMLResult.nodes('/root/*') x(a)
Select @JSONVersion=@JSONVersion+
Stuff(
  (Select TheLine from 
    (Select ',
    {'+
      Stuff((Select ',"'+coalesce(b.c.value('local-name(.)', 'NVARCHAR(255)'),'')+'":'+
       --Replace(  -- escape double quotes
        Replace( --escape tab properly within a value
         --Replace( --escape return properly
           --Replace( --linefeed must be escaped
             Replace( --backslash too
               Replace(coalesce(b.c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),''),--forwardslash
               '\', '\\'),   
              '/', '\/'),   
         -- CHAR(10),'\n'),   
         --CHAR(13),'\r'),   
       CHAR(09),'\t'), 
      --'"','\"')     
     +''   
     from x.a.nodes('*') b(c) 
     for xml path(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')+'}'
   from @XMLResult.nodes('/root/*') x(a)
   ) JSON(theLine)
  for xml path(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)' )
,1,1,'')
--if @Rowcount>1 Return '['+@JSONVersion+'
Return '['+@JSONVersion+'
]'
return @JSONVersion
end
```

I achieved the expected result but it takes almost 10 to 13 seconds to get the json format result. The time taken to get the xml result is 1 or 2 seconds. I know converting XML to Json takes considerable amount of time.

Can anyone please suggest me any other best way to convert sql server table data to Json.

I am trying to produce results within 1 or 2 secs.

Comment: Upgrade to `SQL Server 2016` and use `FOR JSON`.

Comment: Yes its very similar to For XML, I know it but I am using SQL Server 2012 not able to upgrade at the moment.

Comment: With SQL Server 2016 there'll be native JSON support. There are some [workarounds in the related connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/673824/add-native-support-for-json-to-sql-server-a-la-xml-as-in-for-json-or-from-openjson)

Comment: This article may be useful https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/