# Convert XML to JSON without knowing the XML schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a user-defined function or a stored procedure able to receive any XML and convert it to JSON.

I found many questions and replies about how to convert a XML to JSON, but all of them knows exactly how the XML is composed.

I also found [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322170/convert-sql-server-table-data-from-xml-to-json), with an UDF trying to achieve this, but is not working for me, it returns NULL to any XML I provide.

Code in question:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [uf_xmltojson] 
    (@XMLResult XML)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @JSONVersion NVarchar(max), @Rowcount int

    SELECT @JSONVersion = '', @rowcount = COUNT(*) 
    FROM @XMLResult.nodes('/root/*') x(a)

    SELECT @JSONVersion = @JSONVersion +
                          STUFF((SELECT TheLine 
                                 FROM
                                     (SELECT ',
    {'+
      Stuff((Select ',"'+coalesce(b.c.value('local-name(.)', 'NVARCHAR(255)'),'')+'":'+
       --Replace(  -- escape double quotes
        Replace( --escape tab properly within a value
         --Replace( --escape return properly
           --Replace( --linefeed must be escaped
             Replace( --backslash too
               Replace(coalesce(b.c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),''),--forwardslash
               '\', '\\'),   
              '/', '\/'),   
         -- CHAR(10),'\n'),   
         --CHAR(13),'\r'),   
       CHAR(09),'\t'), 
      --'"','\"')     
     +''   
     from x.a.nodes('*') b(c) 
     for xml path(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')+'}'
   from @XMLResult.nodes('/root/*') x(a)
   ) JSON(theLine)
  for xml path(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)' )
,1,1,'')
--if @Rowcount>1 Return '['+@JSONVersion+'
Return '['+@JSONVersion+'
]'
return @JSONVersion
end
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?